# How to redirect to the method of a controller after user doing authentication on codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, authentication, redirect

I am using the Default Controller to make the user authentication. What I am trying to do is whatever is the page the user request news/add or news/index or themes/all or maps/view, if he is not logged in, he or she will be directed to the log in page and then redirected to the page he wanted to go, not always the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can your the
[CodeIgniter User Agent Library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/user_agent.html) and [Session Library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) to store and use the referring url. The user agent library is basicly accessing the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] value.

NOTE: from the [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) website:

> Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

so this is not a foolproof method.

```
if ($this->agent->is_referral()) {
    $this->session->set_userdata('prev_url', $this->agent->referrer());
}

// later, when login is successful
$prev_url = $this->session->userdata('prev_url');
if( $prev_url ) {
    redirect($prev_url);
}
```

Comment: it is working, but not loading the method, only the previous controller. I didn't need to set the "prev_url" though.

Answer (score 0):

one way is to do it in the constructor of your controller. that way they are redirected before going to the news/add etc.

so for example you create a model called "sentry" and a "getUser()" method to check the browser cookie to see if the user is authorized. if they are not authorized have it return false. if they are authorized have it return $user so then you have it available for your other methods.

```
function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model( 'sentry' );

    if ( ! $this->user = $this->sentry->_getUser() ) 
            { redirect( '/login/', 'refresh' );     }

    }
```

so then for example you could have $this->user->name etc etc available to any method in the controller. And $this->user will also automatically be available in all the view files of this controller.

Answer (score 0):

I do this by extending my controller and I check in constructor if person is logged in or not, if person is logged in I save to the session current URL, and redirect person to the login page (if same constructor is applied (controller one) I make exception to not save current URL to the session) after logging in I call redirect function to the session variable.

How to extend your controller is done here http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY

note that when your controller is extended you use `$this->data['variable_sent_to_view']` and you can omit second parameter of `$this->load->view()`

here is some example code assuming you know how your login controller works

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->output->enable_profiler(FALSE);

        if ($refer = $this->session->flashdata('refer')) {

            $this->data['refer_page'] = $refer; // $this->data['refer_page'] is variable that you are interested in
            unset($refer);

        } else {

            $this->data['refer_page'] = base_url(); //default refer_page

        }


        //check if user is NOT logged in
        if (!$logged_in) {

            $this->_setRefer(); //this is private function

        }
        // else dont care about it
    }

    private function _setRefer() {


        $invalid_method = array('search', 'login'); // if method is 'search' or 'login' url will not save in session (it will stay same as was before)
        $valid_refer = TRUE;


        if (in_array($this->router->method, $invalid_method)) {

            $valid_refer = FALSE;

        }

        if (!(count($_POST) > 0) && $valid_refer === TRUE && !$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('refer', current_url());

        } else {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('refer', $this->data['refer_page']);

        }

    }

}
```

now in after succesful login redirect to $this->data['refer_page'], but note that login controller must by extended by MY_Controller.

this script also takes care about what happens if user made mistake and inserted wrong password (page will reload but "old" url stays)